# Tar file utility - Rust

Tags: file-system, rust

I've been working on building a Rust version of GNU tar following the spec [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html).

As of right now, I've got the binary accepting a single argument, the path to the file/directory to tar, which is passed to a separate library which does the heavy lifting.

The library handles building the Tar record (1 per file), which consists of the header and the file data, if it's not a directory. So far, I can successfully tar single files and multiple files in nested directories, and these tar files can be read by GNU tar as valid (and extracted). I don't have any support for handling sym-links as of yet.

Next step is handling untar-ing a given archive.

I'm new to rust, having only done small toy projects in the past, and wanted feedback if I'm following Rust conventions or if there's more idiomatic ways to write some of my code before I dive headlong into the next piece of functionality.

tar.rs

```
use crate::tar::tar_record::TarRecord;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};
use std::path::PathBuf;
use walkdir::WalkDir;

const TAR_MAGIC: &str = "ustar\0";
const TAR_VERSION: u32 = 0u32;
const DEV_MAJOR_VERSION: u64 = 0o0;
const DEV_MINOR_VERSION: u64 = 0o0;

const BLOCK_SIZE: usize = 512;

const NAME_SIZE: usize = 100;
const PREFIX_SIZE: usize = 155;

mod tar_record;

pub struct Tar {
    files: Vec<TarRecord>,
}

impl Tar {
    pub fn new(path: PathBuf) -> Tar {
        let mut root = path.clone();
        root.pop();
        let root = root.as_path();

        if path.is_dir() {
            let files: Vec<TarRecord> = WalkDir::new(path)
                .into_iter()
                .filter_entry(|e| !crate::is_hidden(e))
                .filter_map(|e| e.ok())
                .map(|file| TarRecord::new(file.into_path(), root))
                .collect();

            return Tar { files };
        }

        let record = TarRecord::new(path, root);

        Tar {
            files: vec![record],
        }
    }

    pub fn write_tar(&self, path: &mut PathBuf) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let result_path = path;
        result_path.set_extension("tar");
        let mut writer = BufWriter::new(File::create(result_path).unwrap());

        for record in self.files.iter() {
            record.write_record(&mut writer)?
        }

        // write 2 empty blocks to signify end of TAR
        write!(writer, "{:\0<size$}", "", size = BLOCK_SIZE * 2)?;

        writer.flush()
    }
}
```

tar_record

```
use crate::tar::{
    BLOCK_SIZE, DEV_MAJOR_VERSION, DEV_MINOR_VERSION, NAME_SIZE, PREFIX_SIZE, TAR_MAGIC,
    TAR_VERSION,
};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Write};
use std::os::macos::fs::MetadataExt;
use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use users::{get_group_by_gid, get_user_by_uid};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TarRecord {
    name: String,
    mode: u32,
    user_id: u64,
    group_id: u64,
    size: u64,          // size of the file in bytes
    modified_time: i64, // Unix time file modified
    type_flag: TypeFlag,
    linkname: String,
    username: String,
    group_name: String,
    file: File,
}

impl TarRecord {
    pub fn new(path: PathBuf, root: &Path) -> TarRecord {
        let name = path
            .strip_prefix(root)
            .unwrap()
            .to_str()
            .unwrap()
            .to_string();

        println!("a {}", name);

        let file = File::open(path.clone()).unwrap();
        let metadata = file.metadata().unwrap();

        let user_id = metadata.st_uid();
        let group_id = metadata.st_gid();
        let modified_time = metadata.st_mtime();

        let type_flag;
        let size;
        if path.is_dir() {
            size = 0;
            type_flag = TypeFlag::Directory;
        } else {
            size = metadata.len();
            type_flag = TypeFlag::ARegFile;
        }

        let username = get_user_by_uid(user_id).unwrap();
        let group_name = get_group_by_gid(group_id).unwrap();

        TarRecord {
            name,
            mode: (metadata.permissions().mode() & 0o07777),
            user_id: user_id as u64,
            group_id: group_id as u64,
            size,
            modified_time,
            type_flag,
            linkname: "".to_string(),
            username: username.name().to_str().unwrap().to_string(),
            group_name: group_name.name().to_str().unwrap().to_string(),
            file,
        }
    }

    pub fn write_record(&self, writer: &mut impl Write) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        self.write_header(writer)?;

        if self.type_flag != TypeFlag::Directory {
            self.write_file(writer)
        } else {
            Ok(())
        }
    }

    fn write_file(&self, writer: &mut impl Write) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let mut reader = BufReader::new(&self.file);
        loop {
            let buf = reader.fill_buf()?;
            let len = buf.len();
            if buf.is_empty() {
                break;
            }
            writer.write_all(buf)?;

            reader.consume(len)
        }
        let residual = BLOCK_SIZE - (self.size as usize % BLOCK_SIZE);
        if residual != BLOCK_SIZE {
            write!(writer, "{:\0<size$}", "", size = residual)?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }

    fn write_header(&self, writer: &mut impl Write) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let mut vec_writer: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

        // Write all elements of the header to the vector
        write!(
            vec_writer,
            "{name:\0<name_size$}{mode:06o} \0{user_id:06o} \0{group_id:06o} \0{size:011o} {modified_time:011o} {checksum}{typeflag}{linkname:\0<100}{magic:\0<6}{version:02}{username:\0<32}{group_name:\0<32}{dev_major:06o} \0{dev_minor:06o} \0{prefix:\0<prefix_size$}",
            name = self.name,
            name_size = NAME_SIZE,
            mode = self.mode,
            user_id = self.user_id,
            group_id = self.group_id,
            size = self.size,
            modified_time = self.modified_time,
            checksum ="        ",
            typeflag = self.type_flag as u8,
            linkname = self.linkname,
            magic = TAR_MAGIC,
            version = TAR_VERSION,
            username = self.username,
            group_name = self.group_name,
            dev_major = DEV_MAJOR_VERSION,
            dev_minor = DEV_MINOR_VERSION,
            prefix = "",
            prefix_size = PREFIX_SIZE,
        )?;

        let sum: u64 = vec_writer.iter().map(|&x| x as u64).sum();

        let mut checksum: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        write!(checksum, "{:06o}\0 ", sum)?;

        println!("Length is {}", vec_writer[148..156].len());
        println!("Length is {}", checksum[0..].len());

        vec_writer[148..156].swap_with_slice(&mut checksum[0..]);
        writer.write_all(&vec_writer)?;

        // Header is exactly 12 bytes shy of a single block.
        // Write 12 nulls to fill the block before moving on.
        write!(writer, "{:\0<size$}", "", size = 12)
    }
}

#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, Ord, PartialOrd, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[allow(dead_code)]
enum TypeFlag {
    ARegFile = b'\0',
    Link = 1,
    Directory = 5,
}
```

Utilities (library root)

```
use walkdir::DirEntry;

pub mod tar;

fn is_hidden(entry: &DirEntry) -> bool {
    entry
        .file_name()
        .to_str()
        .map(|s| s.starts_with('.'))
        .unwrap_or(false)
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but this line seems suspicious to me: 
write!(checksum, "{:06o}\0 ", sum - 64)?;

What is that doing? How many bytes is the checksum ( 2? 8? ). What is going on?

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood Spec defines checksum as `char [8]`, so `u64`. However, it also defines all numerics as "Each numeric field of width w contains w minus 1 digits, and a null". So in practice, its 6 bytes (6 bytes for the checksum, 1 null, 1 space). The `sum - 64`, is due to an unknown off-by-one error resulting in my checksum being exactly 64 higher than it should be. And all numerics are written in octal, again based on the spec, hence the `"{:06o}" ` formatter.

Comment: Reading here 

https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html

it says "When calculating the checksum, the chksum field is treated as if it were all blanks." Is that the problem perhaps, it looks like you haven't added in the blanks?

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood, I'm writing the header twice, once in memory and the second time to the file. The in-memory is going to a `Vec<u8>`, and the checksum is written as all 0's. This is done in the first (very large) write block. This Vec is then summed to get what the checksum is supposed to be, and the values are swapped into the Vec which is then written to the file.

Comment: It says blanks not zeros? Ascii zero is 48, blank is 32, difference of 16, not sure how that can account of a difference of 64 though. Sorry, I am a bit lost here!

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood you were right, I was using ASCII nulls (0x00), and should have been using ASCII blanks (0xA0). Changing this fixed my off-by-one error. Updating above code to reflect this. Thanks for the insight!